# Pipfile.lock out of date / cannot create regular file 'requirements.txt'

Tags: python, heroku

When I try to push my project to Heroku with `git push heroku master` I get this output:

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.6
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: cp: cannot create regular file '/app/tmp/cache/.heroku/requirements.txt': No such file or directory
remote: -----> Installing python-3.7.3
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
remote:        Your Pipfile.lock (e78d47) is out of date. Expected: (d89661).
remote:        Aborting deploy.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I have tried running `pipenv lock` but that didn't fix the problem.

My `Pipfile` looks like this:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
flask = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
numpy = "*"
opencv-python = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "I have tried running 1pipenv lock1 but that didn't fix the problem"—how did you do this, exactly?

Comment: @Chris I just ran it in the terminal with my pipenv activated inside the folder of the Pipfile.

Comment: Locally? Did you commit the changes to `Pipfile.lock` and push the new commit to Heroku?

Comment: @Chris oh damn, I forgot to commit the changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried running `pipenv lock` but that didn't fix the problem

Make sure to commit the modified `Pipfile.lock` and push your commit to Heroku. Just running that command locally won't do it.